# GAE launcher Python installation can't import module six

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I just recently launched my local Google App Engine sandbox Python application after not touching it in a while. It seems the following import is giving me problems, but this didn't happen before.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

This results in the import error:

```
 ImportError: No module named six
```

I'm not sure what changed with the GAE launcher but it seems the six module is no longer included. I checked on my system and this module is installed globally.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was introduced by some updated libraries included with Google App Engine launcher. To avoid the import error, you'll need to include module six into you project. It can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six)